# Deleting multiple rows throws 'there is no row position at 2' IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter how many rows you want to delete:");
del = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
try
{

    for (int i = 0; i <del; i++)
    {
        dt.Rows[i].Delete();
        dt.AcceptChanges();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n************************************\n");
}
```

Comment: Isn´t the error clear enough? Obviously your datatable doesn´t have three (!!) rows, so deleting that one with index 2 (indexes are zero-based) results in that error. There are only indexes zero and one existing probably.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, or - as I've put in my answer, it's because of the way rows being removed "shuffles" the rows so what was the row @ position 2 becomes the row at position 1 after deleting the first row, and so on, and so on,...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're having is that each time you delete a row, the rows "move up" so when you delete `dt.Rows[0]`, what was `dt.Rows[1]` becomes `dt.Rows[0]`, because you're accessing each row by its *index* rather than by a unique identifier for it. The below is a worked example that will show this if you run it (I've based it on your code so that you've got some context to it):

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("IdColumn", typeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { i } );
}

var del = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < del; i++)
{
    dt.Rows[i].Delete();
    dt.AcceptChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("Deleted row number {0}, rows remaining in table are {1}, IdColumn for Rows[i] is {2}", i, dt.Rows.Count, dt.Rows[i]["IdColumn"]);
}

Console.WriteLine("\n************************************\n");
```

One option available to you is to use LINQ and replace the above with something along the lines of:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("IdColumn", typeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { i } );
}

var del = 3;

dt = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(del).CopyToDataTable();
```

If you look at the contents of `dt` after running the second code snippet, you should see that the rows with a value of {0, 1, 2} for `IdColumn` have been removed, which looks like the outcome you're after.